# What does $\frac{d^6y}{ dx^6}$ mean?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

The whole question is that 
If $f(x) = -2cos^2x$, then what is $d^6y \over dx^6$ for x = $\pi/4$?

The key here is what does $d^6y \over dx^6$ mean?

I know that $d^6y \over d^6x$ means 6th derivative of y with respect to x, but I've never seen it before.

Comment: It's old notation but generally accepted.

Comment: Does that mean sixth derivative? But I thought $d^6y \over d^6x$ means sixth derivative.

Comment: I have never seen the notation $\frac{d^6y}{d^6x}$ for the sixth derivative, I only know $\frac{d^6y}{dx^6}$.

Comment: $f'(x)$ also means the derivative of $f$ just like $\frac{d}{dx}[f(x)]$.  Different notations have been used for the same thing throughout history.

Comment: $\frac{d^6 y}{d^6 x}$ is nonsensical notation. The sixth derivative is $\frac{d^6 y}{d x^6}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The symbol "$\frac d{dx}$" is used to indicate a single derivative (with respect to $x$).

We treat repeated application of this operator symbolically as "powers" of the operator (as if it were ordinary multiplication by an ordinary fraction), writing "$\frac{d^n}{dx^n}$" to indicate $n$ successive applications of "$\frac d{dx}$".

The notation is peculiar but wholly accepted as traditional. In particular, one might wonder why "$dx^n$" rather than "$(dx)^n$" in the "denominator"; but evidently the "$d$" isn't regarded as an independent factor, rather "$dx$" is regarded as an atomic term.

One eventually accepts it and gets used to the notation.

Comment: If you think of the limit definition of the derivative, the $n^{th}$ derivative is the $n^{th}$ order difference $\Delta^n y$ ($\Delta$ iterated $n$ times), scaled by the $n^{th}$ power of the increment $\Delta x$, $\dfrac{\Delta^ny}{\Delta x^n}$.

Comment: If the $\mathrm d$ in $\mathrm dx$ were considered an independent factor, you could just cancel it out in $\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}$ to obtain $\frac{y}{x}$. Which obviously is not a valid transformation.

Answer (score 2):

If you recall the definition of the derivative, then you can write
\begin{align}
y'(x) &= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac {y(x+h) - y(h)}h \\
y''(x) &= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac {y'(x+h) - y'(x)}h = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\frac {y(x+2h) - y(x+h)}h - \frac {y(x+h) - y(x)}h}h = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac {y(x+2h) - 2y(x+h) + y(x)}{h^2}
\end{align}
so you can see, that denominator is in fact raised to the power, and numerator isn't. So, by convention
$$
y'' = \frac {d^2y}{dx^2}
$$
where $d^2y$ means a certain infinitesimal difference operator, and $dx^2$ means actual power.

Same idea holds for higher derivatives.

Comment: It is interesting to see that you can apply the derivative to the expressing where the limit is applied to. Is that a general rule?

Comment: @NoChance you can check it by applying Taylor series expansion to each term under the limit.

Comment: Thx for your reply, the concept is interesting and I need to think about it for sometime. Thx again.

Answer (score 1):

The correct notation for the sixth derivative is

$$\frac{d^6 y}{dx^6}$$

not $\frac{d^6 y}{d^6x}$. This notation is meant to be suggestive of taking the sixth power of the operator $d/dx$; that is,

$$\frac{d^6 y}{dx^6} = \underbrace{\frac{d}{dx} \cdots \frac{d}{dx}}_{6} y$$

Imagine $dx$ being treated as a single term, of which there are $6$.

Answer (score 0):

For convenience, first transform

$$-2\cos^2(x)=-1-\cos(2x).$$

Then the sixth derivative is $$2^6\cos(2x),$$ because $\cos(x)''=-\cos(x)$ and because of the scaling of the variable .

At $x=\dfrac\pi4$, $$0.$$